# Notification when UITableView changes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I often have a `UITableViewController` with an edit button, which I like to disable when there are no rows in the table. To keep this in sync, I enable/disable the button every time something happens that might update its `dataSource` - adding the first row, deleting the last row, in `viewDidLoad`, etc. Whenever I add some new functionality that can affect the contents of the table, I have to remember to incorporate this logic.

Is there some delegate of the `UITableView` that I can use to simplify this? A way to know whenever the table (or it's `dataSource`) is modified, where I can check the number of items in the `dataSource` and enable/disable accordingly.

Alternatively, any other approaches would be welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *are* the data source. So you do know whenever the data source changes, if you care to know. In other words, the reason you're having this problem is that you're treating the model (in the model-view-controller architecture) as an alien being. Instead, treat the model as something of your own. Take charge of your model. For example, is the model an array? Then wrap it in a class of your own, to which all commands to change the array must be given. That way, it can emit a notification whenever it is told to change the array.

It is also possible under certain circumstances to use Key-Value Observing to get notified when something changes, and you could look into it, but with primitives like arrays and dictionaries it is possible that this will be more trouble than it's worth. Again, you're likely to be happier wrapping your model storage in your own class, whose observability via KVO you can manage yourself.

Comment: Yes that's what I was anticipating - I can maybe subclass NSArray and set up a protocol to notify the delegate when an item is added or removed. Unfortunately my data source is a little more complex than that (it's an array of dictionaries, each of which contains another array) so its not quite so straightforward - but certainly possible. I was hoping there might be something built-in or simlper that I was overlooking.

Comment: I should also mention my data source is somewhat atypical - it is actually a method that queries core data and massages the objects into the aforementioned array of dictionaries (with some caching for performance). So the data source is updated automatically whenever I create a managed object - there is no direct adding or removing to/from it. So I would have to do something in awakeFromInsert I guess. I'll think on it.

Comment: Do not subclass NSArray. Wrap it. - However, since you're actually doing something more complex, there may be a better way. Possibly you should pose the question again (a different question) with a better description of the data source.